# Probability of Roots outside the unit disc

Tags: probability-inequalities, complex-numbers

Consider a random polynomial $p(z)=\sum_0^n A_i z^i.$ where $A_i,i=0,12,3,..,n$ are iid uniform variables in the interval $(0,1).$ I want to show that that the probability of the root with min modulus lying outside the unit disc approaches 0 as the degree becomes larger and larger.That is,the probability that all roots lie outside the unit disc approaches zero as n goes to infinity.

**My Attempt** We observer that the probability that $A_0 \geq A_1 ...\geq A_n$ holding true is $\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$ so that from Enstrom Kakeya theorem,it follows that the all roots lying outside is at least $\frac{1}{(n+1)!} $ for an nth degree polynomial. Unfortunately, for large n this  though true becomes devoid of any  useful information. I try the next approach by considering the product of roots as follows:

$$|z_1.z_2 \cdots.z_n|=|A_0/A_n|$$
If $\xi$ is the modulus of the root with max modulus we have $$ \xi^n \leq \left|\frac{A_0}{A_n}\right|$$
Denoting by $W$ the random variable $\left|\frac{A_0}{A_n}\right|^{1/n}$ and considering
$$ \xi <W<w,$$ we have:
$$P(\xi \leq w) \geq P(W \leq w)=F_W(w) ,$$
$F_W$ being the CDF of $W$
This leads to $$ P(\xi >w) \leq 1-F_W(w)$$
Now if for $w>1,$ the RHS of the approaches 0,then we are done. But I don't know how that can be done.

Comment: Please be clear, so that we don't have to parse the details just to know what the question is!  Which "disk" are you referring to?  Any?  The unit disk?  An arbitrary disk centered at the origin?  Are you considering all complex roots or just the real roots?

Comment: I mean unit disc and I am considering all roots,real or cmplex

Comment: Do you want to raise $z$ to the power $i?$

Comment: @AgnostMystic May I ask the source of this problem?

Comment: It was a typo..thank you for pointing it

Comment: There is no source ..It just came to my mind and I was wondering whether the kind of approach I am talking will serve to settle the it or not .

Comment: @AgnostMystic If this is just your conjecture, that is, no one knows if it is true or false, it is quite meaningless to discuss if a "proof" works or not.

Comment: @Zhanxioung,it a well known result in theory of  random polynomial with some distribution on the coefficients that the roots of a large degree polynomial tend to concentrate uniformly on the unit circle.If we invoke those results then it immediately follows that the  almost all roots of the polynomial in the question almost lie within  or on the unit circle ,hence they lie  outside the unit disc with vanishing probability.I mean the claim is definitely true .My question is about the possibility of proving it using the approach that I pointed